# Calculations with Fractions by operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My C++ code includes a class Fraction with the variables "zaehler" (numerator) and "nenner" (denominator). These Fractions should be added, subtracted, multiplied and divided.

I used operator overloading, to do the calculations and the basic combinations work fine and the results are reduced correctly:

[image]

When it comes to combining the operators, it mostly worked as expected, but here comes my problem:

[image]

The first three are correct, but the combination of multiply and subtracted messes up.
While debugging I noticed that one variable seems to have two values:

[image]

How can the variables (dif.zaehler and dif.nenner) have different values?

The class and the overloadings (ggT = greatest common divisor, kgV = smallest common denominator):

```
Fraction::Fraction()
{
    zaehler = 1;
    nenner = 1;
}

unsigned int Fraction::ggT(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    if (b != 0)     //b = 0, wenn a % b = 0, bedeutet Division ohne Rest
    {
        return ggT(b, a % b);
    }
    else
    {
        return a;
    }
}

unsigned int Fraction::kgV(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    int facA[30], facB[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)    
    {
        facA[i] = a * (i + 1);
        facB[i] = b * (i + 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)    
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++)
        {
            if (facB[k] == facA[i])     
            {
                return facA[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

Fraction Fraction::operator-(const Fraction& b)
{
    Fraction dif;
    int temp_zaehler;



    int zaehler_a = ((float)this->zaehler / this->nenner) * kgV(this->nenner, b.nenner);        
    int zaehler_b = ((float)b.zaehler / b.nenner) * kgV(this->nenner, b.nenner);
    dif.zaehler = (zaehler_a - zaehler_b);
    dif.nenner = kgV(this->nenner, b.nenner);

    if (dif.zaehler < 0)
    {
        temp_zaehler = dif.zaehler;
        dif.zaehler /= ggT(dif.zaehler*-1, dif.nenner);
        dif.nenner /= ggT(temp_zaehler*-1, dif.nenner);
    }
    else
    {
        temp_zaehler = dif.zaehler;
        dif.zaehler /= ggT(dif.zaehler, dif.nenner);
        dif.nenner /= ggT(temp_zaehler, dif.nenner);
    }

    return dif;
}


Fraction Fraction::operator*(const Fraction& b)
{
    Fraction prod;
    int temp_zaehler;
    prod.zaehler = (this->zaehler) * b.zaehler;     
    prod.nenner = (this->nenner) * b.nenner;        


    if (prod.zaehler < 0)
    {
        temp_zaehler = prod.zaehler;
        prod.zaehler /= ggT(prod.zaehler * -1, prod.nenner);
        prod.nenner /= ggT(temp_zaehler * -1, prod.nenner);
    }
    else
    {
        temp_zaehler = prod.zaehler;
        prod.zaehler /= ggT(prod.zaehler, prod.nenner);
        prod.nenner /= ggT(temp_zaehler, prod.nenner);
    }
    return prod;
}
```

And the line in main.cpp (getString outputs the numerator and denominator as string):

```
std::cout << "d * e - b = " << d.getString() << " * " << e.getString() << " - " << b.getString() << " = " << (d * e - b).getString() << "\n";
```

Comment: It looks like you get an integer overflow

Comment: Be careful with implicit conversions between unsigned and signed. The fact that one of the factions is printed as `-2 / 5` means that at least the numerator is signed. Converting a `int` value of `-2` to `unsigned`, which is likely happening implicitly somewhere in your code, yields `4294967294`

Comment: Btw: the standard library has [`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) and [`std::lcm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm). Consider using that implementation instead of implemeneting your own...

Comment: I don't recommend using float btw. This can result in inaccuracies being introduced. Rather than doing `int zaehler_a = ((float)this->zaehler / this->nenner) * kgV(this->nenner, b.nenner); ...` I'd recommend `auto resultDenominator = std::lcm(nenner, b.nenner); auto resultNumerator = (zaehler * (resultDemominator / nenner)) - (b.zaehler * (resultDenominator / b.nenner)); auto factor = std::gcm(resultDenominator, resultNumerator); return {resultNumerator/ factor, resultDenominator/factor};` (you'll still need to make sure to not have any implicit casts from signed to unsigned messing this up...

Comment: Furthermore I'd recommend implementing the operators at namespace scope to allow implicit conversions to take place. E.g. `class Fraction{ ... Fraction(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1); };` would allow for `auto x = 1 + Fraction{1, 2};` with an operator implementation at namespace scope, but your implementation wouldn't allow this. Furthermore default value of arithmetic types is 0 and I recommend you use this convention for your class too, to be consistent with this; initialize to `0 / 1` in the default constructor instead of to `1 / 1`...

Comment: Tbh, I'd say - never use unsigned .A fraction where denominator or both are negative is fine, just an "unnormalized" form. A normalization method would  right the signs and wound turn something like `-9/-12` into `3/4` and such method would be separate, not an implicit opreation of each operator. After all, such isn't cheap

Comment: Thank you. But what I still dont get is, why is there two value for the same variable. Actually the -1209 and 150 are correct. Why doesn't the program use that?